# How do I format dates in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, templates

I'm modifying a pre-existing script in Xcode to customize my file headers. The script is Perl and it's not my best langage. :)

I just need to insert the current date in the header in dd/mm/yy format.

Here is my script :

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
# Insert HeaderDoc comment for a header
#
# Inserts a template HeaderDoc comment for the header.
use strict;

# get path to document
my $headerPath = <<'HEADERPATH';
%%%{PBXFilePath}%%%
HEADERPATH
chomp $headerPath;
my $rootFileName = &rootFileNameFromPath($headerPath);

print "/*";
print " * $rootFileName\n";
print " * Project\n";
print " *\n";
print " * Created by Me on ";
# in bash it would be something like that :
# date +%d/%m/%y | awk '{printf "%s\n", $1}';
print " * Copyright 2009 My_companie. All rights reserved.\n";
print " *\n";
print " */\n";

sub rootFileNameFromPath {
    my $path = shift;

    my @pathParts = split (m'/', $path);
    my $filename = pop (@pathParts);
    my $rootFileName = "$filename";
    $rootFileName =~ s/\.h$//;
    return $rootFileName;
}

exit 0;
```

I've just modified the print command so don't ask me for the rest of the code :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than removing `strict` (!), why not just make the code `strict` clean?

```
my ($mday, $mon, $year) = (localtime(time))[3, 4, 5];

$mon  += 1;
$year += 1900;

printf "%02d/%02d/%02d\n", $mday, $mon, $year % 100;
```

Maybe even better (since more familiar looking to someone who asked in terms of Bash):

```
# At the top, under use strict;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;

# then later...
my $date = strftime "%d/%m/%y", localtime;
print "$date\n";
```

Funny coincidence: [Perl Training Australia](http://perltraining.com.au/) publishes semi-regular [tips](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/) (you can get them via email or online), and just today there's [a new one](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2009-02-26.html) on `strftime`.

Comment: POSIX's strftime is the correct way to format dates... that or another class to do it, like Date::Manip.

Comment: Date::Manip is very powerful, but many of its features have high performance penalty.  Pesonally, I normally use the first example here.

Comment: @spoulson: Yup, the Date::Manip documentation itself has a whole section explaining why you generally don't need/want Date::Manip. I generally use POSIX's strftime since it automagically takes care of the details that I might otherwise forget or mess up (add 1 to month, 1900 to years).

Answer (score 9):

You could also use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime) and related modules, which is of course complete overkill for a little script like this. But for a larger app, you should use solid modules rather than doing everything the long way. For the record, with DateTime you'd write:

```
DateTime->today()->strftime('%d/%m/%y');
```

Or you could use the more modern CLDR format language:

```
DateTime->today->format_cldr('dd/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@time = localtime(time);
$mday = $time[3];
$mon = $time[4]+1;
$year = $time[5]+1900;
print "$mday/$mon/$year\n";
```

Should do it.

Edit:

```
printf "%02d/%02d/%4d",$mday,$mon+1,$year+1900";
```

Will take care of the padding with zeroes too.

Comment: it gaves me some error : "Global symbol "$sec" requires explicit package name" do you see the point?

Comment: made a few changes to code. But seems to be working for me without the error you're getting.

Comment: try removing 
    use strict;

Comment: @trex279: still have some warning about $sec and the other unused variable, but seems to do the trick, thx.

Comment: declare the variables by using 'my' before the first list, instead of removing the use strict, which is not usually considered a good idea.