# WriteOutput Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a perl subroutine similar to this php function.

```
private function writeOutput($msg, $type) {
                  echo date("H\:i\:s") . " - [$type] .  > $msg\n";
          }
```

I need a little help defining `$msg` and `$type`.

```
sub WriteOutput {
    $sec = sprintf ("%02d", $sum%60);
    $mins = sprintf("%02d", ($sum%3600)/60);
    $hrs = int($sum/3600);
    print "[$hrs:$mins:$sec]:[$type]>: $msg";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you could try phrasing it differently? Thanks.

Comment: The php function works like this `writeOutput("test", "type1");` so i was wondering if I could get it done in perl too

Comment: People knowing perl need not understand php. consider explaining question independently. What's input, how many arguments to the subroutine?

Comment: What "doesn't work" with the Perl? At the very least, `$sum`, `$type`, and `$msg` should probably come from somewhere - and see `my`. If you just want date-time formatting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575188/how-do-i-format-dates-in-perl for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your PHP subroutine:

```
private function writeOutput($msg, $type) {
    echo date("H\:i\:s") . " - [$type] .  > $msg\n";
}
```

First, Perl doesn't have a *builtin* date formatter. Instead, you have to use a *module* to handle dates.
Also,  you're taking two parameters in your function called `$msg` and `$type`. Perl doesn't use function parameters in the function call. Instead, you use `shift`:

```
use Time::Piece;      # A nice way to handle datetime. Included since Perl 5.10
use feature qw(say);  # Better than `print`. Included since Perl 5.10

sub write_output {
    my $msg        = shift;
    my $type       = shift;

    my $time = Time::Piece->new(localtime);
    say $time->hms . " - [$type] .  > $msg";
}
```

The [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) command is the standard way of taking your function's *input parameters*. [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is the standard Perl module for handling time since Perl 5.10. This is an *object oriented* module. The `->` is similar to the *dot* in most other languages. The `my $time = Time::Piece->new(localtime);` creates a new `Time::Piece` object based upon the current time. The `$time->hms` uses the `hms` method to print out the time in `HH:MM:SS` format.

Note the use of `my` which declares and localizes variables (something that PHP doesn't really have). You should always have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` on all of your Perl programs. Then, you have to *declare* all of your variables with `my`.

Note in Perl, the *standard* way for variables is to use all lowercase and use underscores as separators. This is taken from [Perl Best Practices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) by Damian Conway. You may or may not agree with all of Conway's coding standards, but one of the nice things about standard is that everyone uses them which makes working with other's people code so  much nicer -- whether you like them or not.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, your question is about passing arguments to Perl subroutine.

Perl stores arguments passed to subroutine in special variable `@_`. Add following line at the beginning of your subroutine.

```
my ($msg, $type) = @_;
```

And call this subroutine with

```
writeOutput("test", "type1");
```

Bdw, I hope you're not trying to use global variables here, since `my` is missing.

Apart from that it's not clear what is `$sum`

Answer (score 1):

For this function in PHP:

```
private function writeOutput($msg, $type) {
   echo date("H\:i\:s") . " - [$type] .  > $msg\n";
}
```

Perl offers the possibility to do the same thing:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

sub WriteOutput {
  my($msg, $type) = @_;
  my $date = strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", localtime);
  print "$date:[$type]>: $msg";
}

WriteOutput "Ok", "Not OK?";
```

Gives:

```
[19:12:01][Not Ok?]>: Ok
```